# Hibernate ORM compatability for JDK 8 ARM

Tags: java, hibernate, arm

Hibernate ORM requires JDK 6 or higher. JDK 8 for ARM is mainly used for developeing the applications for embedded systems.

Is hibernate works in  this JDK 8 for ARM platform ??

Comment: Which hibernate version you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate support JDK 8 but some knows bugs/issues that are fixed and closed by Hibernate team. See this [Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-825) ticket which is fixed also check this [link](https://bitbucket.org/montanajava/jpaattributeconverters).As per my experience Hibernate latest version supports JDK 8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Actually there is some difference between JDK8 and JDK8 for arm...I want to know about the compatibility of hibernate w.r.to JDK8 for ARM  but not JDK 8..